# How do you avoid janky animation when using CATransform3DRotate in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I have added the code for it below, basically the animation works where I can have it animate on touching certain points but the issue is that after animation it starts transforming in a weird way. The motion animation on the other hand works fine as you move the device. I am trying to figure out how to prevent it from going from 3D to that flat image that appears afterwords.

```html
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var redView: SpecialView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        redView = SpecialView()
        redView.backgroundColor = .black
        view.addSubview(redView)
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Some Text"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        redView.addSubview(label)
        
        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.text = "Some Description"
        label2.textColor = .white
        label2.numberOfLines = 0
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        redView.addSubview(label2)
        
        redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.trailingAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            
            label2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor),
            label2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            label2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor),
            
            redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.heightAnchor),
            redView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        addParallaxToView(vw: redView)
    }

}

final class SpecialView: UIView {
    
    func findCorner(from point: CGPoint) -> SPPerspectiveHighlightCorner? {
        let width = bounds.width
        let height = bounds.height
        
        let mediumXLeft = width/4
        let mediumXRight = width/2 + width/4
        
        let mediumYTop = height/4
        let mediumYBot = height/2 + height/4
        
        switch (point.x, point.y) {
        case (0...mediumXLeft, 0...mediumYTop):
            return .topLeft
        case (mediumXLeft...mediumXRight, 0...mediumYTop):
            return .topMedium
        case (mediumXRight...width, 0...mediumYTop):
            return .topRight
        case (0...mediumXLeft, mediumYTop...mediumYBot):
            return .mediumLeft
        case (mediumXRight...width, mediumYTop...mediumYBot):
            return .mediumRight
        case (0...mediumXLeft, mediumYBot...height):
            return .bottomLeft
        case (mediumXLeft...mediumXRight, mediumYBot...height):
            return .bottomMedium
        case (mediumXRight...width, mediumYBot...height):
            return .bottomRight
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func makeVector(for corner: SPPerspectiveHighlightCorner, step: CGFloat) -> Vector {
        switch corner {
        case .topMedium: return Vector(x: step * 2, y: 0, z: 0)
        case .topRight: return Vector(x: step, y: step, z: 0)
        case .mediumRight: return Vector(x: 0, y: step * 2, z: 0)
        case .bottomRight: return Vector(x: -step, y: step, z: 0)
        case .bottomMedium: return Vector(x: -step * 2, y: 0, z: 0)
        case .bottomLeft: return Vector(x: -step, y: -step, z: 0)
        case .mediumLeft: return Vector(x: 0, y: -step * 2, z: 0)
        case .topLeft: return Vector(x: step, y: -step, z: 0)
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        startMoving(touches: touches)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        startMoving(touches: touches)
    }
    
    func startMoving(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
        guard let location = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        var identity = CATransform3DIdentity
        identity.m34 = -1 / 500.0
        
        guard let highlightCorner = findCorner(from: location) else { return }
        let corner = makeVector(for: highlightCorner, step: 3.14)
        print(corner)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(identity, (10 * .pi) / 180, corner.x, corner.y, corner.z)
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        var identity = CATransform3DIdentity
        identity.m34 = -1 / 500.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(identity, (0 * .pi) / 180, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        }
    }
}

func addParallaxToView(vw: UIView) {
    
    var identity = CATransform3DIdentity
    identity.m34 = -1 / 500.0

    let minimum = CATransform3DRotate(identity, (315 * .pi) / 180, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    let maximum = CATransform3DRotate(identity, (45 * .pi) / 180, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    let minimum2 = CATransform3DRotate(identity, (135 * .pi) / 90, 0, 1, 0.0)
    let maximum2 = CATransform3DRotate(identity, (225 * .pi) / 90, 0, 1, 0.0)

    vw.layer.transform = identity
    let effect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(
        keyPath: "layer.transform",
        type: .tiltAlongVerticalAxis)
    effect.minimumRelativeValue = minimum
    effect.maximumRelativeValue = maximum
    
    let effect2 = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(
        keyPath: "layer.transform",
        type: .tiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
    effect2.minimumRelativeValue = minimum2
    effect2.maximumRelativeValue = maximum2
    
    let groupMotion = UIMotionEffectGroup()
    groupMotion.motionEffects = [effect, effect2]

    vw.addMotionEffect(groupMotion)
}


struct Vector {
    public var x: CGFloat
    public var y: CGFloat
    public var z: CGFloat
}
```

[image: Janky animation]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing the motion effect fixed it. Seems very odd that I was facing this issue on the simulator.